# how to place the textbox inside the login panel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, vb.net

[image]

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div id="header" runat="server" class="clsHeaderContent">
                <div class="clsDivBody">
                    <table cellpadding="0" border="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 1024px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Main/Home.aspx")%>">
                                    <asp:Image ID="imgLogo" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Logo.png" Style="border: 0" />
                               </a>
                               
                            </td> 
                        </tr>
                            <%
                                    If Not Session("Member_Login_Profile") Is Nothing Then
                            %> 
                                <tr style="height:30px;">
                                    <td align="right" valign="top">
                                         <asp:Button ID="cmdHome" runat="server" Text="Home" />
                                         <asp:Button ID="cmdMyProfile" runat="server" Text="My Profile" />
                                         <asp:Button ID="cmdLogout" runat="server" Text="Logout" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>                        
                                <tr style="height: 5px;">
                                    <td/>
                                </tr>
                            <%
                                End If
                            %>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="clsDivBody bg" style="padding: 15px 0;min-height:730px;">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
        </div>

        <div id="backtotop" style="display: block;">^ Back to Top</div>
        <div id="push"></div>
        <input type="hidden" id="_ispostback" value="<%=Page.IsPostBack.ToString()%>" />
             </form>
```

```html
<form >

                            
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCardNo" runat="server"  MaxLength="20" value="Card No." Text="824488"  onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Card No.':this.value;" />&nbsp;
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqCardNo" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCardNo" CssClass="clsValidationErrMsg" Display="dynamic" ValidationGroup="Login" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regExCardNo" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCardNo" CssClass="clsValidationErrMsg" Display="dynamic" ValidationGroup="Login" />
                                                      
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"   MaxLength="16"  value="thegardensclub123" TextMode="Password" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Password':this.value;" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqPassword" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" CssClass="clsValidationErrMsg" Display="dynamic" ValidationGroup="Login" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regExPassword" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" CssClass="clsValidationErrMsg" Display="dynamic" ValidationGroup="Login" /><br/>
                            
<%--                            <u><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkForgotPwd" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" Text="Forgot your password?" /></u>
--%>                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnLogin" Text="Log In"/>     
        
                             
  </form>
```

The first snippet is my master page, and the second is my login page.
The problem is, if i dont remove the  in master page my textbox in login page, the textbox can not be placed in the panel. 
If i remove the  in master page, its shows me this error "Control 'ctl00_MainContent_oSM' of type 'ScriptManager' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server."
If i remove the  in login, also the textbox can not be placed in the panel. So what should i do?

Comment: soory about that i not sure how to show my current result, so i gave the codes need to view the contents

Comment: why don't you design the form using CSS rather making a table?